# How would I shrink my header's nav when on scroll?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

So what I've been trying to achieve is to shrink my 'nav' when on scroll. As of right now, I have a two part nav bar. The upper part disappears when being scrolled down, and reappears when scrolled up. The bottom part is always visible at all times and the whole nav is fixed to the top.

My problem is the content inside the upper nav div disappears when being scrolled down, instead of the whole nav div shifting up along with the bottom div.

Here are some pics:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgZ56.jpg before and after https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4tCw.jpg

Here's the code:

```
<header>
 <div id="vp-nav" class="fixed-top">
  <nav class="container" id="nav-Upper">
   <div class="zeroed navbar pt-2">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Project one</a>
    <a><i href="#" class="fa fa-podcast fa-2x mr-auto" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
   </div>
  </nav>
  <div id="nav-Lower" class="text-center scrollmenu">
   <a href="#">Tag one</a>
   <a href="#news">Tag two</a>
   <a href="#contact">Tag three</a>
   <a href="#voice">Tag four</a>
   <a href="#about">Tag five</a>
   <a href="#home">Tag six</a>
   <a href="#news">Tag seven</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</header>

<style>
   nav {
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
   }

   nav.hidden {
    transform: translate3d(0,-100%,0);
   }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

            (function() {
                var documentElem = $(document),
                    nav = $('nav'),
                    lastScrollTop = 0;

                documentElem.on('scroll', function() {
                    var currentScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

                    if ( currentScrollTop > lastScrollTop ) 
                        nav.addClass('hidden'); //scroll down
                    else 
                        nav.removeClass('hidden'); //scroll up

                    lastScrollTop = currentScrollTop;
                });



            })();
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a pen with your code and I think the issue is that you were applying the transform to the nav instead of #vp-nav. Try this CSS and JS instead (HTML unchanged)

```
*** CSS ***

#vp-nav {
  position: fixed;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  background-color: red;
  top: 0;
}

#nav-Upper {
  font-size: 100px;  /* For example */
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: grey;
}


*** JS ***

(function() {
  var documentElem = $(document),
      nav = $('nav'),
      lastScrollTop = 0,
      navUpperHeight = $('#nav-Upper').outerHeight();

  documentElem.on('scroll', function() {

    var currentScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    if ( currentScrollTop > lastScrollTop ) 
      $('#vp-nav').css('top', '-' + navUpperHeight + 'px'); //scroll down
    else 
      $('#vp-nav').css('top',0); //scroll up

    lastScrollTop = currentScrollTop;
  });
})();
```

See https://codepen.io/MSCAU/pen/aayjMR. (The earlier pen which led to the discussion below and prompted this edit can be seen at: https://codepen.io/MSCAU/pen/YOQRem)

Comment: Close! This makes the whole ‘vp-nav’ disappear. I’m only aiming to make “nav-Upper” disappear, while the div with the classes of ‘text-center’ & ‘scrollmenu’ shift up and be fixed....thank you for your help!

Comment: **edit: I added an 'id' of 'nav-Lower'. I'm trying to have this div visible at all times, it just shifts up when page is being scrolled/'nav-Upper' disappears**

Comment: I've added a background-color: red to #vp-nav (see Codepen again) and only to top part of the navigation is disappearing. So I'm either not quite understanding what you're seeing or your CSS - based on your screenshots - is more complex than what you provided in your OP. Glad it helped anyway!

Comment: After looking at it for a bit, I realized your codepen has a margin above the ‘vp-nav’ while mine is completely at the top. When I scrolled on my code, everything disappeared. But when I added a margin of a few px’s, some of it was being shown!

Comment: We concidentally got a good result in the earlier Codepen because the height of #nav-Upper matched the top margin on the page. In that case, here's an updated pen which will work with any size content in #nav-Upper: https://codepen.io/MSCAU/pen/aayjMR. Note it's using CSS instead of class to control the shift as we need it to be dynamic. There are other ways you could do this but perhaps this will suffice? If that works for you, I'll update the answer above for others to refer to.

Comment: Yes! I essentially did the same thing with adding a padding to the bottom of the whole nav of 53px, with intentions of going back to tidy things up. Seems like you did just that! Same results, just better code.

Comment: No worries. Glad to help when I have time!